# Images are not loaded even after network is restored before scrolling in flutter

Tags: flutter, image, networking

```
                      Image(
                            image: NetworkImage(widget.contentImageLink[0]),
                            height: 200,
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
                              return Container(
                                height: 200,
                                color: Colors.grey.shade900,
                              );
                            },
                          ),
```

The above code display container when there's not internet and supposed to load image when network is restored but it doesn't load the image on it's own unless I scroll the listView to move it out of screen. When scrolled back it loads the images.

How can I make it load images ASA network is restored?

Comment: create function to check internet connection, if internet stable call setstate

Answer (score 0):

You can use `connectivity_plus: ^2.3.0` to check if the connection is reestablished.
Just add this listener to your widget and call setState(){} when the connection is reestablished.

```
late StreamSubscription _subscription;

@override
initState() {
_subscription = Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen(
          (result) {
             if (result == ConnectivityResult.wifi ||
                result == ConnectivityResult.mobile ||
                result == ConnectivityResult.ethernet) {
              setState(){}
            }
          },
        );
}

@override
dispose() {
    _subscription.cancel();
}
```